# Anything comparable to Windows' "Network Location" in MacOS?

Tags: macos, network, security

This is my first Mac. On Windows I can set each network connection as either Home, Work or Public using "Network Location". Each mode has different sharing and security options. Is there a way to do this for the Mac? For example, at home I want to turn on File Sharing, but in Public I want it turned off. Furthermore, in Public I'd like to automatically "Enable stealth mode" in my security settings.

Basically, I want to automatically adjust network and security settings based on which network I'm connected to.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot adjust both the security and network settings at once unless you use applescript.

You can however set the network settings to Home, Work or Public as follows.

Navigate to:

### >Applications/System Preferences.app/Network

Select the dropdown at the top which says Location:
[image]

Navigate to the bottom and select `"Edit Locations ..."`
[image]

Then click the plus sign and add the location you want.
[image]

You will then need configure all the required parameters, such as DHCP v Static etc.

Once this is done you can set up an applescript which will modify your firewall settings depending on which location you are at.